# Java Elevated Privileges

Tags: java, windows

So, I'm trying to develop an application in Java, but it needs admin access to do what it needs to do. I've been trying to get it working for a while, but I'm stuck. I don't particularly want to wrap it in an exe through a program such as Launch4j, I'd just like to be able to put something into my program (which if it matters, is using JavaFX) which will request for admin access to do what it needs to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I've tried using a manifest file to request admin level access, but I've either did it wrong or it wouldn't work. Is putting it in a wrapper the only way to do it with it coming across as being one jar file?